# Displaying the whole excel file as a table using PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a excel file with multiple sheets. I want to display the data in excel file as a table using PHP without inserting to database.

Comment: Share your best attempt (code) with us so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using simplexlsx PHP Library

below is the library code

https://github.com/fahadpatel/simplexlxs.git

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

require_once __DIR__.'/../src/SimpleXLSX.php';

echo '<h1>Read several sheets</h1>';
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('countries_and_population.xlsx')) {

    echo '<pre>'.print_r( $xlsx->sheetNames(), true ).'</pre>';

    echo '<table cellpadding="10">
    <tr><td valign="top">';

    // output worsheet 1

    $dim = $xlsx->dimension();
    $num_cols = $dim[0];
    $num_rows = $dim[1];

    echo '<h2>'.$xlsx->sheetName(0).'</h2>';
    echo '<table border=1>';
    foreach ( $xlsx->rows( 1 ) as $r ) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i ++ ) {
            echo '<td>' . ( ! empty( $r[ $i ] ) ? $r[ $i ] : '&nbsp;' ) . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

    echo '</td><td valign="top">';

    // output worsheet 2

    $dim = $xlsx->dimension( 2 );
    $num_cols = $dim[0];
    $num_rows = $dim[1];

    echo '<h2>'.$xlsx->sheetName(1).'</h2>';
    echo '<table border=1>';
    foreach ( $xlsx->rows( 2 ) as $r ) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i ++ ) {
            echo '<td>' . ( ! empty( $r[ $i ] ) ? $r[ $i ] : '&nbsp;' ) . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

    echo '</td></tr></table>';
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

Comment: I would like to know how to parse only a specific sheet(using the name of sheet) in one excel file using this.

Comment: Please refer to the below link 

https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to do encode the parsed file so that I can remove all the invalid characters and make the data to be in readable format.